# In Spring MVC either @Controller or Static resource mapping works not both together if I map both to root

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I've mapped my Dispatcher Servlet to "/". 
And in dispatcher servlet xml, I 've mapped resources to "/**". 
I am not able to access Controllers. 
Is there some way to tell Spring to look for Controller mapping first then if unavailable then only look for Static resource mapping.

Comment: why dont you map your resources like this ? : /resources/**  instead of "/**"

Comment: The reason i am not mapping resources to /resources/** is
I am building a rest app and I want it to be accessible on root like 
"mydomain.com".
My whole Angular JS app is in a "UI-APP" directory an i am mapping root to UI-APP directory.
I don't want to copy html and js to the web root.
And i also don't want to change any of Angular JS code for changes in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the default dispatcher servlet in your mvc-dispatcher servlet

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

You can find more info in the spring doc [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler)

Comment: Although it works but i don't quite understand how.
According to what i believe default-servlet-handler is not aware of any of spring's controllers so how does adding <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
makes Spring Controllers work ?